# jQuery getJSON doesn't have enough time to execute before dialog close

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, getjson

I am using jQuery's UI Dialog to draw a dialog (`my-ui-dialog`) to the screen and present the user with some `<input>`s and other controls. When the user clicks the dialog's *OK* button, I want the UI dialog to fire an AJAX/JSON message to my server (via `getJSON`), allow the server to process that call, and then close the dialog after the response is received from the server. Then the user should be redirected (via `window.location`) to another web page.

Here's my code:

```
$("#my-ui-dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 255,
    width: 300,
    buttons: {
        "OK" : function() {
            var f = $("#fizz").val();

            $.getJSON(
                "/myserver/do-something",
                {
                    fizz: f
                },
                function() {
                    $("#my-ui-dialog").dialog('destroy');
                }
            );

            // When I leave this in the code works great.
            // When I comment the alert out, the getJSON call never
            // hits the server-side.
            alert("Returned from the backend...");

            window.location = "/myserver/some-other-url"
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

When I leave that `alert` box in, and wait a few seconds (with the alertbox drawn to screen), the `getJSON` method seems to have enough time to hit the server and return. But if I comment out the `alert` the request never even hits my server. I can tell this by adding a log message to the beginning of the handler listening at `/myserver/do-something`. This is also a Java web app and I don't see any evidence of Tomcat receiving the request, and I don't see the `HTTP` request being generated when using Firebug to debug. All 3 of these indicate that the request is simply not hitting the server at all.

What are my options here? Can I make the jQuery sleep for a few seconds? That feels like an ugly solution; there must be a better way to use the jQuery API... thanks in advance!

Comment: You have an ASYNCHRONOUS and you are treating it like it is synchronous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your dialog close and `window.location` code in the `getJSON` callback. That's why there's a callback.

Comment: But why isn't an http request even being generated?

Comment: @MadSkunk: It is, but the request is aborted when the page is unloaded.